# How to fix org.apache.avro.message.BadHeaderException: Unrecognized header bytes: in Java Kafka consumer?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, avro

I'm implementing an Avro deserializer for a Kafka consumer. However when I go to run the consumer I get an error deserializing the value saying that there are unrecognized header bytes.

First I decided to inspect the record in question which caused the error. I did this in using a 3rd party visualization tool for kafka. I could see that the record was correct and the 3rd party tool could consume the Avro messages from the topic correctly. So this told me the problem is likely with my implementation of the deserializer.

Here is my implementation of the Deserializer class

```java
public class UserRecordDeserializer implements Deserializer<userRecord> {
    ...
    @Override
    public userRecord deserialize(String topic, byte[] data){
        if (data == null){
            return null;
        }

        try {
            ByteBuffer userRecordBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(data);
            userRecord newRecord = decodeUserRecord(userRecordBuffer);
            return newRecord;
        } catch (IOException | RuntimeException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error deserializing value", e);
        }

    }

    private userRecord decodeUserRecord(java.nio.ByteBuffer data) throws IOException{
        try {
            userRecord temp = new userRecord();
            return temp.fromByteBuffer(data);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the DECODER and fromByteBuffer method of the Avro generated class.

```java
  private static final BinaryMessageDecoder<userRecord> DECODER =
      new BinaryMessageDecoder<userRecord>(MODEL$, SCHEMA$);

  public static userRecord fromByteBuffer(
      java.nio.ByteBuffer b) throws java.io.IOException {
    return DECODER.decode(b);
  }
```

```sh
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error deserializing value
    at com.package.serdes.UserRecordDeserializer.deserialize(UserRecordDeserializer.java:30)
    at com.package.UserRecordDeserializer.deserialize(UserRecordDeserializer.java:11)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer.deserialize(Deserializer.java:58)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.parseRecord(Fetcher.java:1030)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.access$3300(Fetcher.java:110)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$PartitionRecords.fetchRecords(Fetcher.java:1250)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher$PartitionRecords.access$1400(Fetcher.java:1099)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchRecords(Fetcher.java:545)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher.fetchedRecords(Fetcher.java:506)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollForFetches(KafkaConsumer.java:1269)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1200)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1176)
    at com.package.consumer.ActivitiesKafkaSimpleConsumerImpl.run(ActivitiesKafkaSimpleConsumerImpl.java:25)
    at com.package.RunConsumer.main(RunConsumer.java:11)
Caused by: org.apache.avro.message.BadHeaderException: Unrecognized header bytes: 0x00 0x00
    at org.apache.avro.message.BinaryMessageDecoder.decode(BinaryMessageDecoder.java:147)
    at org.apache.avro.message.MessageDecoder$BaseDecoder.decode(MessageDecoder.java:139)
    at org.apache.avro.message.MessageDecoder$BaseDecoder.decode(MessageDecoder.java:127)
    at com.package.models.userRecord.fromByteBuffer(userRecord.java:71)
    at com.package.serdes.UserRecordDeserializer.decodeUserRecord(UserRecordDeserializer.java:42)
    at com.package.serdes.UserRecordDeserializer.deserialize(UserRecordDeserializer.java:27)
    ... 13 more
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason against using the existing Confluent Avro serializers?